# Swagger stopped working

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, swagger

in a asp.net core 2 web.api project, I added Swagger using this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?tabs=visual-studio%2Cvisual-studio-xml

and it worked perfectly

Then I had to rerun the function to build models from entity framework db-first, and here after I get this fault in the swagger gui:

```
No operations defined in spec!
```

I have removed a readded the swagger, but no change. downloading the

/swagger/v1/swagger.json

It looks like this:

```
{"swagger":"2.0","info":{"version":"v1","title":"My API"},"paths":{},"definitions":{}}
```

Startup.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions;
using SmoEventApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;

#region AddedUsings

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
#endregion

namespace SmoEventApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        #region ConfigureServices
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            // Register the Swagger generator, defining one or more Swagger documents
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
            });

            var connection = @"Server=xxxx\MSSQL01;Database=yyy;User Id=user;Password=pp;ConnectRetryCount=0";
            services.AddDbContext<DCMMContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));


        }
        #endregion

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwagger();

            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea why I dont get any info from swagger any more?

Kåre

Comment: Can you update you question with the content of your `Configure` and `ConfigureServices` methods from the `Startup` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be annotations in controllers that was missing

Comment: For anyone else running into this problem. I needed to add `[ApiController]` to the controllers